# Why is the FormCollection in my controller empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-mvc-4

### Background

I am coding an API layer in C# using MVC 4 Web API Project (ASP.NET).

I have written a test action in my controller like this:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public string TestAction(FormCollection fc)
{
    return "test";
}
```

I am using Poster in FireFox to test a form post:

- content-type is set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- Body from parameters is set to foo=bar&bar=foo

Here is my route:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute("PostDefault", "{controller}/{action}");
```

### Question

I am able to hit the controller with no problem when posting a url and parameters from Poster, but if I put a breakpoint on `return "test";` and then hover over the `FormCollection` that is passed in (`fc`) It shows that an empty array of strings was passed in rather than my values (e.g. `string[0]`).

I have done this loads of times using jQuery `$.post()` on the client with no problems receiving the form collection.

What is it failing in this case?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that this is an action defined inside an API controller ([`ApiController`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)). If this is the case you cannot use `FormCollection`. This is used for normal controller actions, not API controllers (personally I don't use it even in normal controller actions but that's another topic, see the next paragraph to understand what I am using instead).

You should define a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action take this view model as parameter:

```
public class TestController: ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public string TestAction(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Notice that the correct attribute for an API controller is `[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]` and not `[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]` as in your code.

Also I would recommend you sticking to RESTful conventions:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute("PostDefault", "{controller}");
```

and then:

```
public class TestController: ApiController
{
    public string Post(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Now the HTTP Verb (POST in this case) determines the controller action to be invoked:

```
POST /test
Server: http://example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 15
Connection: close

foo=bar&bar=foo
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.  In the case of my API layer, I am simply accepting a request from one application and then passing the request on to a separate service so my layer is really just a pass-through (long story).  It's a pity that I have to set up a model just to pass these requests along as it can cause problems in the future if the model changes on either end.  That, of course, is not a comment on your answer.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Darin--Is there any reason I should not use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form` in order to get the form parameters without having to set up an explicit model?  I just tried it and it works perfectly, but I am wondering if there is a good reason why you did not mention this approach (e.g. a performance consideration).  Thanks!

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` => forget about unit testing. Not to mention that the Web API could also be self hosted. If you self host it `HttpContext.Current` no longer exists and your code will break.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov but what if I have a controller action that needs to take more dynamic input like `params object[]` in C# or `varargs` in C?  A fixed model type won't work.